# Python (django) regular expression does not work

Tags: python, django, regex

I have such expression:

```
^[0-9()|&~ ]*$
```

It should pass through strings like: `'1 & 2 & 3'` or `'(4&1)|(2&3)'`

But when I type string: `'1 & 2iuasjhdawiudjsa'`, It passes this string. So then I got an error: "Name 'Trueiuasjhdawiudjsa' is not defined".

What's wrong? Why validators.RegexValidator doesn't raise an exception?

Please, help!

Fails in the third validator. If I remove 3rd validator then RegexValidator raises an error, as it should to.

```
expression = models.CharField(
        blank=True, max_length=225,
        validators=[validators.RegexValidator('^[0-9()|&~ ]*$'),
                    validate_logical_expression,
                    check_logic_operation_positions] # fails here, when try to 
                                                     # check logic
            ]
    )
```

Comment: [Your regex does not match](https://regex101.com/r/xE2Hlo/1) the string you mention

Comment: @Victor Stribizev, so this is a problem: regex does not match, but RegexValidator doesn't return an error, and because of that, program fails when it tries to process the string through the second validator:

Comment: So, the problem is not the regex, but how you are using it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , I've edited the question. Can you see the problem?

Comment: show us a usage example ( how you save data )

Comment: @iklinac I use standart save() method of the model.

Comment: @ЯригаОлег please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of saving code, where your data is coming from, do you use forms etc..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolve this problem:

```
def check_logic_operation_positions( ...):
    try:
        ...
    except NameError:
        raise ValueError(_('invalid name'))
```